# SSDT Publish fails because 'System.DirectoryServices' failed verification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, ssdt, sql-clr

Imported an existing database (SQL2012) to an SSDT project in VS2017 and when trying to deploy it to my local instance (SQL2016) I get the error message:

> CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'System.DirectoryServices' failed because
>   assembly 'System.DirectoryServices' failed verification.

I've no issue creating the Assembly in my database in SSMS when pointing it to:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.DirectoryServices.dll

In my SSDT project I have the target framework set to .NET Framework 4 under SQLCLR.

The reference to System.DirectoryServices has Generate Sql Script and Model Aware options set to true and permission set to Unsafe.

Database settings also has the trustworthy option enabled.

Running `select * from sys.dm_clr_properties` on my instance returns:

```
directory   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
version v4.0.30319 
state   CLR is initialized
```

What do I need to change to get my project to publish successfully?

Full error message below.

```
Creating [System.DirectoryServices]...
Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.directoryservices, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.
(221,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6218, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'System.DirectoryServices' failed because assembly 'System.DirectoryServices' failed verification. Check if the referenced assemblies are up-to-date and trusted (for external_access or unsafe) to execute in the database. CLR Verifier error messages if any will follow this message
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::PurgeAccessRules][mdToken=0x6000009][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::PurgeAuditRules][mdToken=0x6000010][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::get_AccessRightType][mdToken=0x6000015][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::get_AccessRuleType][mdToken=0x6000016][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::get_AuditRuleType][mdToken=0x6000017][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::ModifyAccessRule][mdToken=0x6000008][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::ModifyAuditRule][mdToken=0x600000f][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::AccessRuleFactory][mdToken=0x6000011][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::AuditRuleFactory][mdToken=0x6000013][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::AccessRuleFactory][mdToken=0x6000012][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::AuditRuleFactory][mdToken=0x6000014][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::.ctor][mdToken=0x6000001][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity::AddAccessRule][mdToken=0x6000002][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurit...
(221,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.DirectoryServices]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM 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
An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
```

Comment: Are the 2012 and 2016 instances on the same physical server or different? If different, what is the highest patch-level of the .NET Framework on each server? It could be that this library went from pure MSIL to mixed-mode in a .NET Framework update and is no longer valid for use. Else you grabbed the DLL from the wrong place (i.e. don't get from GAC, get from original .NET Framework location in `C:\Windows\..`.

Comment: 2012 is server-side and 2016 is on my laptop

Comment: In SSDT the reference points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.DirectoryServices.dll` if I try to create this assembly in my database in SSMS i get the same error

Comment: Ok, so the 2012 is more likely to NOT be up to the latest .NET Framework update. But with the most recent comment here with the location, I can say that reference Assemblies don't work. Try using: `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Dir‌​ectoryServices.dll` instead.

Comment: Same error regardless of which file I reference to in my SSDT project

Comment: Did you see my answer? It works on my system. I believe I have up to .NET Framework 4.6.2 installed, but not 4.7. Not sure if that makes a difference. You need to make sure that your change to the project is picking up the new location to get the DLL from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61553/discussion-between-mheptinstall-and-srutzky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this behavior is intended by SSDT or a change from prior versions, but what is happening is that the "reference assembly" is being pulled in. Reference Assemblies aren't the actual Assembly and so they won't work to import into SQL Server. What is frustrating here is that even if you use "Browse" when adding the Reference and select **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.DirectoryServices.dll** and then select "true" for `Model Aware` under its properties, SSDT will still pull in the Reference Assembly (at 114 kb) instead of the DLL that you pointed to (which is 413 kb). More specifically, it will pull in the reference assembly from the folder that corresponds to the "Target Framework Version" set in project properties (e.g. 4.6.1 == **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1** ).
If it matters, I am using Visual Studio 2015 and SSDT for Management Studio 2017 (i.e. v14).

However, while not ideal, I was able to get this to work by copying the DLL to a non-system folder. I copied the full **System.DirectoryServices.dll** in **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\** into my project folder, and then I added an "existing item" to point to the DLL (in my project folder), which has a "build action" of `None`, and then set the Reference properties to: Owner = `dbo`, Permission Set = `UNSAFE`, and Model Aware = `True`. After that it worked.

If this DLL had any dependencies then I imagine that I would need to copy them into my project as well. But I am not 100% sure about that part.

I guess we can add this experience to the list of reasons to not use unsupported .NET Framework libraries and/or SSDT ;-)

Comment: I get the same error when pointing to that file. SSDT does not allow you to create assembles that way in your project `SQL70502: The assembly source is not valid. Only binary literals are allowed.`

Comment: Yes, I have changed the reference in my project. It was originally `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Dir‌​ectoryServices.dll` and I've tried both `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.DirectoryServices.dll` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.DirectoryServices.dll` neither publish correctly from the project

Comment: I've moved the discussion to chat...

Comment: I have updated my answer with a way to get this to work. We can probably remove the comments here and on the question as they are in the chat room now.